# Excel VBA Subscript Out of Range error on array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am getting the Subscript out of range error in my VBA code when checking if the second element of an array is equal to a different variable.  Here is the code:

```
Sub Pay_Period_Summarization()
'
' Pay_Period_Summarization Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'

Dim wb As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range
Dim rg2 As Range
Dim row As Object
Dim row2 As Object
Dim Department As String
Dim sumpay As Currency
Dim count As Integer
Dim Dept As Variant


count = 0
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("AD2").End(xlDown))

Department = ""
For Each row In rg.Rows

    If count = 0 Then
        sumpay = sumpay + row.Cells(1, 11).Value
        Department = row.Cells(1, 1).Value
        count = count + 1
    Else

        If Department <> row.Cells(1, 1).Value Then

            Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Journal Entry")
            ws2.Activate
            Set rg2 = ws2.Range("B4", ws2.Range("P4").End(xlDown))

            For Each row2 In rg2.Rows
                Dept = Split(row.Cells(1, 2), "-")

                If Dept(1) = Department Then
                    row.Cells(1, 4).Value = sumpay
                Else

                End If
            Next row2
            sumpay = 0


        Else

            'MsgBox (row.Cells(1, 11).Value)
            sumpay = sumpay + row.Cells(1, 11).Value
        End If
    End If

    'MsgBox (sumpay)
Next row

End Sub
```

I am getting the error at the "If Dept(1) = Department Then" line and it is saying that the array element is out of range.  I am new to VBA so please forgive my mistakes.

Comment: It means that in that string there is no `-`  you need to check if you are using the correct data.  Put a `Debug.Print row.Cells(1, 2)` in and make sure you are seeing what you think you should.

Comment: You are assuming Dept contains 2 elements, but this must not be the case.  Do all the cells you are splitting contain a "-"?

Comment: `Dept = Split(row.Cells(1, 2), "-")` - should you be splitting `row2.Cells(1,2)` ?

Comment: Tim - You were correct.  Simple naming convention mistake on my part.  Thank you!